# Not showing pdf files for non-users of my site

Tags: php

I have a site that I have developed using PHP and it has users who can access the site with their username and password. . I have a directory in my host and in this directory I keep my PDF files. I want only my members access these PDF files. However since the path is knkown, how can I force for nonusers not to download the pdfs . Is there a solution to that. 
For example if the path is entered in browser like www.mysite.com/pdfs/sample.pdf and if the person is not a member of the site I want to direct him/her to the signup page. İs there a way to that in php?

Comment: Don't serve those files directly, have a PHP script serve them after validating the session.

Comment: You could rewrite the URL to a PHP script that would check the login status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

1. Enable `mod_rewrite` module in Apache HTTP Server.
2. In the `.htaccess` file, rewrite the URL which requests for any PDF file to your PHP file.
3. Create a PHP file which will authenticate the user.
4. In the PHP file, if user is authenticated, serve the required PHP file as a download. The PDF file name can be found in `$_GET['file']`.

**PHP Code to serve a file as download**

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.pdf"');
readfile("{$_GET['file']}.pdf");
```

**Rewrite Rule in `.htaccess` file**

```
RewriteRule ^(.+).pdf$  /user_pdf_download.php?file=$1.pdf [L,NC,QSA]
```

Here I took some assumptions. You can modify as required.